# Saving Local Data in Metro Style App

Tags: javascript, windows, windows-runtime, visual-studio-express, winjs

I want to make a score mechanism in windows 8 metro style app and want to save that score locally using Windows.Storage.ApplicationData i'm having quite a hard time since im new to visual studio and App building.

```
var applicationData = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.current;

var localSettings = applicationData.localSettings;

// Create a simple setting

localSettings.values["totalPike"] = '0';

// Read data from a simple setting

var totalPike = localSettings.values["totalPike"];

if (!totalPike) {
    // No data
}
else {
    // Access data in value
}

// Delete a simple setting

localSettings.values("totalPike");
```

That is how windows handles app data from msdn

```
$(document).ready(function () {

        var clicks = 99;

        $("#totalScoreTestButton").click(function () {
            totalPike = totalPike + clicks
            $("#totalScoreTest").text(totalPike);
        });
});
```

This is the function i use to add the score to the total score preatty basic at the time but whenever i close the app and start it again no score is saved. Can someone help me in this, and if possible explain me how Metro apps handle local data?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For example:

```
(function () {
"use strict";

WinJS.Namespace.define("PersistenceManager", {
    stateFile: "game_state",

    saveState: function () {
        var state = {
            game_state: game_state,
            level: levelIndex,
            score: SCORE,
            playerLives: player_lives,
            compLives: comp_lives
        };

        WinJS.Application.local.writeText(PersistenceManager.stateFile, JSON.stringify(state));
    },

    loadStateAsync: function () {
        var app = WinJS.Application;

        return app.local.exists(PersistenceManager.stateFile).then(function (exists) {
            if (exists)
                return app.local.readText(PersistenceManager.stateFile).then(function (data) {
                    return JSON.parse(data);
                });
            else return null;
        });
    },

});
})();
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but i used the Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.current to save the data so i guess it saves the files in a .dll or some place else.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this code. It works very well during the execution of the App (visual studio 2015 javascript Apache Cordova) but it does not persist across invocations. Save data OK, read data OK. Close App and launch again, no data. What am I missing?

I ended up using:
window.localStorage.setItem(PersistenceManager.stateFile, JSON.stringify(state));
and
return JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem(PersistenceManager.stateFile));